# How to let locally generated packets pass through PREROUTING chain?

Tags: networking, iptables, proxy

I would like to let locally generated packets pass through PREROUTING chain bacause I want to use

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d somewebsite.com -j TPROXY --on-port 32794
```

to redirect all packets (generated by a local process) heading to somewesite.com to local port 32794.

Many people suggested this instead:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d somewebsite.com -j REDIRECT --to-ports 32794
```

but **REDIRECT will modify packet header** which I am trying to avoid. I have to use TPROXY, it's the only type of target that doesn't modify packet headers.

So what should I do to let locally generated packets pass through PREROUTING chain? Maybe using loopback? But I am not sure whether loopback changes packet headers either...

Comment: I have the same question, Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

iptables is set of rules (or ruleset), which can be found inside chains. Chains are inside the tables.

In your case, you used the `REDIRECT` target but this actually modifies the packets to change the destination address which might not be acceptable, and it is bound to the `nat` table in most cases.

The `TPROXY` target provides similar functionality and relies on `mangle` table.
Simply add rules like this to the iptables ruleset:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d your.ip.address.here --dport 80 -j TPROXY --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1 --on-port 32794 --on-ip=127.0.0.1
```

Note: I also used the mark but these should not alter the TCP header.

Comment: The problem is locally generated packets don't pass through PREROUTING chain